# Zip file extraction when restoring a database

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I've created a backup and restore procedure for my application. When the backup is run, it will create a .zip file of the SQLite database in the same directory as the database.

When restoring the database, it will rename the database, changing it from `EPOSDatabase.db3` to `tempEPOS.db3`

Then, it takes the selected file and extracts it to the same location, under the name `EPOSDatabase.db3`, before deleting the renamed temporary database.

```
string dbPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

if (File.Exists(dbPath + "/tempEPOS.db3"))
  {
    File.Delete(dbPath + "/tempEPOS.db3");
  };

  File.Move(dbPath + "/EPOSDatabase.db3", dbPath + "/tempEPOS.db3");

  ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(dbPath + "/" + fileToRestore, dbPath + "/EPOSDatabase.db3");

  File.Delete(dbPath + "/tempEPOS.db3");
```

My issue is that when I then have code that opens the connection, for example when I open the system settings page after the restore has been carried out, I get an error:

> "Could not open database file: /data/user/0/com.companyname.ACPlus_MobileEPOS/files/EPOSDatabase.db3 (CannotOpen)"

As a further debug test, I added this code to the startup of the application:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
   string strFile = Convert.ToString(file);
}

public readonly string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "EPOSDatabase.db3");

var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
db.CreateTable<Category>();
db.CreateTable<SystemSettings>();

db.Close();
```

In the foreach loop, it only found the original .zip file that I was trying to restore from.

Then when it reaches the line 
`var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);`

it fails to create the database with the message

> "Could not open database file: /data/user/0/com.companyname.ACPlus_MobileEPOS/files/EPOSDatabase.db3"

It seems like the file doesn't exist, so hasn't extracted properly, but if that was the case then why does it not just create a new database, rather than try to open it?

Comment: recheck your extraction logic

Comment: @Nkosi I can't see where the logic is wrong? It checks for any old, renamed databases that weren't deleted, before renaming the current database. It then extracts the .zip file to the same directory and name as the database path uses, before deleting the old version - what am I missing?

Comment: specifically [`ExtractToDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2). You are extracting the contents of the zip file to a **directory** called `EPOSDatabase.db3`. Did you actually take a look at the location to see what was happening because of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extraction logic needs to be rechecked.

Specifically [`ExtractToDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> Extracts all the files in the specified zip archive to a directory on the file system.
>
> ```
> public static void ExtractToDirectory (string sourceArchiveFileName, string destinationDirectoryName);
> ```

In the original code

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(dbPath + "/" + fileToRestore, dbPath + "/EPOSDatabase.db3");
```

The contents of the zip file are extracting to a **directory** called `{path}/EPOSDatabase.db3/`.

If the goal was just to extract from the archive to the directory then only the directory location is required.

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(dbPath + "/" + fileToRestore, dbPath);
```

Additionally, a check should be done to make sure the desired file actually exists after the restore before deleting the old file.

```
//... extraction code omitted for brevity

if (!File.Exists(dbPath + "/EPOSDatabase.db3")) {
    //...either throw error or alert that database is not present

    //...could consider return old file back to original sate (optional)
} else {
    File.Delete(dbPath + "/tempEPOS.db3");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I realised what you were referring to after re-reading the docs. Interestingly it does now open the connection, so that issue has been solved, it now fails to read from the SystemSettings table, claiming it doesn't exist. This shouldn't change the database at all, should it?

Comment: check further back to make sure that the backup was done correctly to begin with. If the restore does not have the table then it was not in the original backup.

Comment: Oh, it appears to be because I'm including the file name in the `startPath` of the `CreateFromDirectory` method. If I remove this, it will backup the entire folder rather than just the database, though. How can I just zip up a single file, rather than the whole folder?

Comment: create a ZipArchive and add the specific file individually. You open a stream to the file and pass that to the archive. There are many answers here that show how to do that.